# PHP Session issue on GoDaddy Codeigniter

Tags: php, session

Codeigniter Session is not working on **godaddy hosting**  while its **worked on localhost** & **Other Server** like Hostinger.in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solutions by Updating the **PHP Version**  from **cPanel** on goDaddy Its work for me